# Change only specific column names based on a data table

Tags: r

I have a table (`dt_replace`) with the actual columns to replace and their corresponding new column:

```
column new
col1    new1
col2   new2
col3   new3
...    ...
```

My original table (`dt`) the one i need to rename has 100 columns and `dt_replace` has only 50 columns.

So far I tried using dplyr library with function rename:

```
c = dt_replace$column
r = dt$new
rename(dt, c = r)
```

But it didn't work, then I tried the following using ColNames:

```
colnames(dt)[colnames(dt) %in% dt_replace$column] <- dt_replace$new
```

It worked but unfortunately, columns are added in the wrong order...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `match`

```
colnames(dt)[match(dt_replace$column, names(dt))] <- dt_replace$new
```

Adding a reproducible example

```
dt <- mtcars
dt_replace <- data.frame(column = c("mpg", "hp"), new = c("new1", "new2"), 
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

colnames(dt)[match(dt_replace$column, names(dt))] <- dt_replace$new

head(dt)
#                  new1 cyl disp new2 drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160  110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160  110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108   93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258  110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360  175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant           18.1   6  225  105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```